# Interrupting Thread in Java for hanged process

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupted-exception

If i have a thread something like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(myThread);
t.start();

private static Runnable myThread = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try{
            String line=null;
            while ((line = eStream.readLine()) != null){
                //do something
            }
         }
         catch (Exception e){}
    }
};
```

Now what happens in while loop, at times the `readLine()` is hanged because it is expecting input from external process. So in that case what i am trying to do is to setup a timer and if it expires, i `interrupt this thread t` with `t.interrupt();`

Now when i try to catch `InterruptedException` after the try block, i am getting compile time error. Can someone tell me in this scenario, how can i catch Interrupted Exception?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the code that causes the compile time error?

Comment: @marchaos actually the error message says Unreachable catch block for InterruptedException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body. So i am confused where in the code do i have to catch this exception

Comment: my bad, i had missing import java.io.InterruptedException;
and i thought i could not catch this exception there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

interrupt won't free a blocking readLine() call.  You have to close the stream to do that.

You are catching the InterruptedException already (and ignoring it) with this line

```
catch (Exception e){}
```

This won't work

```
line = eStream.readLine().toString()
```

As it will throw a NullPointerException when you reach the end of file.  Remove the `.toString()`

Comment: So i can close the stream from another thread by declaring it static? However if you see my comment above for my understanding i would like to know where do i have to catch this exception, as Eclipse IDE gives that message as shown in my comment above, thank you

Comment: You don't have to make the stream static, you can define it before you pass it to the Runnable or make the Runnable a type which has a close() method.

Comment: thank you for pointing in the right direction. Sure i will try now.

Comment: I have tried but i can't close the blcoked IO Stream. It just does nothing, if i try to close it from anywhere, that call is also stuck with nothing happening. Actaully i am not reading file, rather reading output from windows cmdline using Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Comment: In that case, I would try Process.destroy()

Answer (score 2):

From the doc for [InterruptedException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html):

> Thrown when a thread is waiting, sleeping, or otherwise paused for a
>   long time and another thread interrupts it using the interrupt method
>   in class Thread.

I suspect what you're interested in is [InterruptedIOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InterruptedIOException.html):

> Signals that an I/O operation has been interrupted. An
>   InterruptedIOException is thrown to indicate that an input or output
>   transfer has been terminated because the thread performing it was
>   interrupted.

I would check out [this JavaSpecialists newsletter](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html) on cleanly shuttin gdown threads and particularly the subsection **What about threads blocked on IO?** which covers this area in some detail.

Comment: thank you very much, very interesting article to read. Im gonna try this InterruptedIOException and see if it works for me